# How do i rotate a model a predefined degrees

Tags: roblox

I want to know how I can rotate a model 90 degrees without going over. I am working on making an animation for a model and I need to know.

Comment: Have you any code you can show? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Understanding-CFrame will be helpful to you

Comment: Sorry i didn't answer sooner, i  haven't tried anything yet i just want to know

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand but if you are asking how to rotate a model 90 degrees from a script here is how.

```
local model = workspace.Model --Get your model
--Make sure you set the PrimaryPart of the model (what you want the model to rotate around)

local PrimaryPartCFrame = model:GetPrimaryPartCFrame() --Get the CFrame of the primary part

local rotation = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(90),0,0) --Create a CFrame rotated 90 degrees on the x axis

local RotatedCFrame = PrimaryPartCFrame * rotation --Creates new rotated cframe that is the primary part rotated 
--(see https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/CFrame-Math-Operations to understand)

model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(RotatedCFrame) --Rotate the entire model with the new cframe
```